# The Cytoscape v3.9.0 application does not start

Tags: cytoscape

I have a question regarding Cytoscape. I just downloaded the newest version (v3.9.0) for Windows, but I am not able to open the actual application. Before I used v3.6.1 which ran perfectly fine, but I want to make use of the KEGGscape app which requires Cytoscape v3.8.0 or higher.

I have deleted the previous installation of Cytoscape, as well as made sure the cache was cleared. In addition, I downloaded the correct version of Java (Java version 11) and checked the system requirements with the script available on the website, which summarised: "Succes! You are ready to run Cytoscape 3.9.0."

So I am not exactly sure what I am missing and why it is not starting and hope anyone can help.
Thank you in advance.

Kind regards,

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to hear you are having problems.  When you say it doesn't start, does it correctly install, and the application doesn't start when you double-click it, or does the installer never start?  If it's the former -- Cytoscape installs, but doesn't start, you could try opening up a console window and run cytoscape.bat from the directory that you installed it.  That should give us more information about what the problem is.  There should also be a file called framework-cytoscape.log in the CytoscapeConfiguration\3\ directory in your home.  That will give us more information also.

-- scooter

Comment: Yes so I indead meant that Cytoscape is installed, but then the application does not start. I have now tried to run .bat file as well, but that didn't work either and I cannot seem to find the framework-cytoscape.log. Maybe that could be part of the problem. I have also checked windows defender and make sure everything was enabled for Cytoscape specifically, so that would not interfere with the launching of the program.